# AWS Update table not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm uisng [updateTable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateTable-property) of DynmaoDB and I'm passing the following params object:

```
{
    "TableName": "movies",
    "AttributeDefinitions": [{
            "AttributeName": "subtitle",
            "AttributeType": "S"
        }],
    "GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates": [{
            "Create": {
                "IndexName": "subtitle",
                "ProvisionedThroughput": {
                    "ReadCapacityUnits": "5",
                    "WriteCapacityUnits": "5"
                },
                "KeySchema": [{
                        "AttributeName": "subtitle",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    }],
                "Projection": {
                    "ProjectionType": "ALL"
                }
            }
        }],
    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": "5",
        "WriteCapacityUnits": "5"
    }
}
```

but it gives me the following error:

- UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'AttributeDefinitions' found in params
- UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Create' found in params.GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates[0]]

But based on the the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateTable-property)  I need to pass them?! So why is it giving me this error?

**UPDATED:**

Thanks to Daniela Miao's suggestion my problem is fixed by changing the SDK version; but I have run into another issue; again based on the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateTable-property), if we want to create multiple GSIs we need to have multiple objects in "GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates" field, so I'm passing the following params, but it does not update the GSIs; however if I'm just creating one GSI (passing one object in "GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates" field, it works); here is the params I'm passing for creating multiple GSIs:

```
{
    "TableName": "movies",
    "AttributeDefinitions": [{
            "AttributeName": "id",
            "AttributeType": "N"
        }, {
            "AttributeName": "title",
            "AttributeType": "S"
        }, {
            "AttributeName": "subtitle",
            "AttributeType": "S"
        }],
    "GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates": [{
            "Create": {
                "IndexName": "title",
                "ProvisionedThroughput": {
                    "ReadCapacityUnits": "5",
                    "WriteCapacityUnits": "5"
                },
                "KeySchema": [{
                        "AttributeName": "title",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    }],
                "Projection": {
                    "ProjectionType": "ALL"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "Create": {
                "IndexName": "subtitle",
                "ProvisionedThroughput": {
                    "ReadCapacityUnits": "5",
                    "WriteCapacityUnits": "5"
                },
                "KeySchema": [{
                        "AttributeName": "subtitle",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    }],
                "Projection": {
                    "ProjectionType": "ALL"
                }
            }
        }]
}
```

Am I passing the params in a wrong format?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which SDK version are you using? I believe adding an index to an existing table is a new capability that was recently released, so it should be supported only in the newest SDK version 2.1.8: http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/SDK/JavaScript/3682546508553819

Comment: Yes, you were absolutely right, I was trying to use the new feature, which was released a few days ago! But, I wonder why Amazon does not update the documents well, still in the documentation, which I referred to says"API Version:2012-08-10", where they have this feature. Anyway thanks for your help man :-)

Comment: Glad to know it worked out for you! Could you clarify where the wrong documentation is? I think they should fix it, so I'll submit a request. Thanks very much!

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateTable-property top of the page says "API Version:2012-08-10" Thanks

Comment: I ran into another issue when I'm adding multiple GSIs, I updated my question, would you mind letting me know if I'm passing the params in the correct format or not? Again thanks for your help :-)

Comment: I just added my question in a new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402003/creating-multiple-gsis-by-updatetable-dynamodb

I appreciate your feedback there!