# Creating multiple GSIs by updateTable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm uisng [updateTable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateTable-property) of DynmaoDB and based on the documentation, if we want to create multiple Global Secondary Indexes (GSIs) we need to have multiple objects in "GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates" field, so I'm passing the following params, but it does not update the GSIs; however if I'm just creating one GSI (passing one object in "GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates" field, it works); here is the params I'm passing for creating multiple GSIs:

```
{
    "TableName": "movies",
    "AttributeDefinitions": [{
            "AttributeName": "id",
            "AttributeType": "N"
        }, {
            "AttributeName": "title",
            "AttributeType": "S"
        }, {
            "AttributeName": "subtitle",
            "AttributeType": "S"
        }],
    "GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates": [{
            "Create": {
                "IndexName": "title",
                "ProvisionedThroughput": {
                    "ReadCapacityUnits": "5",
                    "WriteCapacityUnits": "5"
                },
                "KeySchema": [{
                        "AttributeName": "title",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    }],
                "Projection": {
                    "ProjectionType": "ALL"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "Create": {
                "IndexName": "subtitle",
                "ProvisionedThroughput": {
                    "ReadCapacityUnits": "5",
                    "WriteCapacityUnits": "5"
                },
                "KeySchema": [{
                        "AttributeName": "subtitle",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    }],
                "Projection": {
                    "ProjectionType": "ALL"
                }
            }
        }]
}
```

Am I passing the params in a wrong format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the DynamoDB [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html#GSI.OnlineOps.Creating):

> You can only create or delete one global secondary index per
>   UpdateTable operation. However, if you run multiple UpdateTable
>   operations simultaneously, you can create multiple indexes at a time.
>   You can run up to five of these UpdateTable operations on a table at
>   once, and each operation can create exactly one index.

Comment: when I do it through the website(AWS console) it says: `Only 1 online index can be created or deleted simultaneously per table (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: LimitExceededException; Request ID: ...` But through the code it creates/deletes one after the other one and it worked! :-) Thanks

Comment: but you can't really run multiple UpdateTable operations simultaneously, can you? I'm trying to do something similar through the java AWS sdk; I'm trying to create a couple of global secondary indexes; when I try to do the 2nd update, I get the same error, from above, about "only 1 online index can be created or deleted simultaneously..."; I found that I had to poll the status of the table and then also poll the status of all the indexes; if any of them were in a status other than ACTIVE, I got an error

Comment: I get the same at @user26270. And `AmazonDynamoDB.updateTable` returns an `UpdateTableResult` but apparently it's not actually finished and there's no `UpdateTableResult.waitForReady()` type function. So frustrating!!!

Answer (score 4):

So the SDK now provides a [`Table.createGSI`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Table.html#createGSI-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.CreateGlobalSecondaryIndexAction-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeDefinition-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeDefinition-) helper function for exactly this purpose. See a [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/create-update-and-delete-global-secondary-indexes-using-the-amazon-dynamodb-document-api/) on the topic.

This helper returns an `Index` object and you can call `index.waitForActive();` to wait until the index has been built before building the next GSI which avoids this Exception.

Comment: How do you do index.waitForActive() equivalent with aws cli ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash you can create your index using the appropriate aws command then wait between updates using the following snippet

```
waitForIndexUpdate() {
  tableActive=false
  while [ "$tableActive" = false ];
  do
    describeTable=$(aws dynamodb describe-table --endpoint-url "$dynamoHost" --table-name "$tableName")
    if [[ $describeTable == *"\"IndexStatus\": \"CREATING\""* ]];
    then
      echo "waiting for index update to complete..."
      sleep .5
    else
      tableActive=true
    fi
  done
}
```